# Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver()); not working

Tags: android

What I'm doing is..when ever I detect certain word in the URL, I have to redirect to to some specified URL and clear the cache/History of the Browser.

The Browser gets redirected correctly, but no cache/History is cleared. On back press browser is redirected back to previous typed URL.

```
if (url.contains("www.facebook.com")) {
                                int resutl = getContentResolver().delete(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, null, null);
                                System.err.println(" result :-"+resutl);
                                Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());
                                Browser.deleteFromHistory(getContentResolver(), url);

Intent mBrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                mBrowserIntent.setPackage("com.android.browser");
                                mBrowserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                mBrowserIntent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID , "com.android.browser");
                                Uri uri = Uri.parse(temp);
                                mBrowserIntent.setData(uri);
                                startActivity(mBrowserIntent);
```

Both these permission are also set.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

Help Needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the history of default browser by using just this simple line of code but I dont know how to delete a specific URL, this work for me:

```
Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());
```

Comment: cannot resolve the method clearHistory
(android.content.contentresolver). why is this happen

Comment: @VV see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

To delete a specific url:

```
Browser.deleteFromHistory(getContentResolver(), "http://www.facebook.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I came here to this question as it was the 1st result in google search and there is no answer, so I wanted to share the answer I found after some search.

Google has removed Permission to read and write bookmark and removed this method after API >= 23 so if you compile your project with sdk version >= 23  you will get

`Cannot resolve method 'clearHistory(android.content.ContentResolver)`

take a look here

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser